# Best search topology for 1 WFE Server,1 App server and 1 SQL Server?

Tags: search, topology

Best search topology for 1 WFE Server,1 App server and 1 SQL Server? Where to configure the index partitioning,query components and other search components

Answer (score 2):

Its depend how big the servers in term of Memory and CPU. As Query components required more resources then it is advisable never configure it on web front end.

I would.

- Use the WFE for web applications only
- Use App server for all applications.

Please check [this topology diagram](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/0/7/A07928F6-5153-4E19-B682-B8D28194095A/sps-2013-topology-model.pdf) recommended by MSFT.